# Create a horizontal slider-type scroller for a text list using jQuery

Tags: jquery

I was looking through other similar questions on here but they all suggest plugins. I am not looking for anything fancy so I'm wondering if someone here can help me out.

I have three phone numbers and when the user presses the previous/next button I would like the previous/next number to appear.

Here is what I have on the front end.

```css
div>ul {
  list-style-type: none;
}

div>ul>li {
  display: inline-block;
}

div>ul>li:nth-child(3), div>ul>li:nth-child(4) {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<link href="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.3.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div>
  <ul>
    <li><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-angle-double-left"></i></a></li>
    <li><p>(111)111-2222</p></li>
    <li><p>(222)222-2222</p></li>
    <li><p>(333)333-3333</p></li>
    <li><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-angle-double-right"></i></a></li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This triggers the next and previous items to add a class to themselves while removing it from the other items in the list.

So if you style .num to display:none and .ind to display block, it will hide everything but the one that is being forced to click itself.

```
$('#prev').click( function() {
    $('.num.ind').prev().trigger('click');

});
$('#next').click( function() {
    $('.num.ind').next().trigger('click');
});

$(".num").click(function () {
    $(".num").removeClass("ind");
    $(this).addClass("ind");
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/7jsojqbq/

Or, this alteration might be more straightforward:

```
$('#prev').click( function() {
    $('.num.ind').prev().addClass("ind");
        $(".num.ind").next().removeClass("ind");
});

$('#next').click( function() {
    $('.num.ind').next().addClass("ind");
         $(".num.ind").prev().removeClass("ind");
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/7jsojqbq/1/